# Blob or ImageURL in android

Tags: android, image, blob

I have a small requirement in my project I would like to show image when there is no internet. I get the image from my web server. I am using ImageLoader / Glide to load the image URL to my ImageView object and I cache that to show image in offline everything is working but when I delete the image or there is new image I have clear cache and then load the image again..When I do this process sometime it works some it doesn't... So I thought why not convert the image into blob. I have converted everything into blob format and stored online now.

I have two questions here:

1. will blob and converting blob in image format make load image faster for offline viewing?
2. Should I send blob in String in Json array and convert it to blob and save it or since I already have imageURL is it faster to convert URL and save to blob format in local database on my phone?

Can somebody throw your ideas for the above requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this test](https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html), the performance of using blobs depends on the size and your configuration of sqlite.

**BLOB server side or client side only**

> So I thought why not convert the image into blob. I have converted
>   everything into blob format and stored online now.

No need to convert on server side tough. If you download the image files as always, you can read content then store in your database as a blob. Then no need to save the image file.

You could potentially shorten your total download time by having your server return all content in one call instead of calling the server for each image (the time it takes to reach the server with the request). The cost would be memory when processing all that data.

The potential for transfer failure always makes me choose to make multiple requests instead of uniques, I'd rather have one corrupt image than a whole sync operation. It's easier to detect and recover.

**BLOB vs files**

I tried using blobs once, then came back to what I always do. Download the file, save it in a folder and save the url in database. Various reasons I did not like are almost purely subjectives

1. Database becomes way way bigger. It complicates thing when debugging, copying, etc.
2. I feel a database (not talking of writes/updates) should help me find information I need, faster and more reliably than I could implement without using one. File content really doesnt go there.. it could (as seen in test linked) actually be slower and make everything else slower too.

I never used a library for such operation so I never got this problem / limitation. If you rather use a library, I'd suggest testing another one.